# Integrating $\int \frac{8 dx}{3 \cos 2x + 1}$ to arctan rather than log

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[Edit: It is becoming increasingly likely that the expected answer containing arctan might be a typo from my book, which is transcribed correctly here, so an answer containing log might be correct after all. Sorry about that and thanks for the answers so far, I've learned a lot!]

I'm trying to integrate:

$$
\int \frac{8 dx}{3 \cos 2x + 1} \\
$$

So I tried substituting $x$ for $z$:

$$
z = \tan \frac{x}{2} \\
\cos x = \frac{1 - z^2}{1 + z^2} \\
dx = \frac{2 dz}{1 + z^2} \\
$$

Then I tried replacing $\cos 2x$ with $2 \cos^2 x - 1$ followed by some work:

$$
\int \frac{4(1 + z^2) dz}{z^4 - 4z^2 + 1} \\
$$

If I try substituting $z$ back to $x$, it seems my answer will contain log rather than the expected arctan:

$$
\frac{x}{3} - \frac{5}{6} \arctan (2 \tan \frac{x}{2}) + C \\
$$

Did I take a wrong turn somewhere?

Comment: Either let $\tan x=z$, or, if you want to work with familiar formulas, let $u=2x$ and then let $z=\tan(u/2)$.

Comment: I then get $\int \frac{4 dz}{2 - z^2}$ but, just like the answer below, I still don't understand how to get arctan.

Comment: A relatively easy way to check the result of the computation of a primitive is differentiation. Differentiate the purported solution and see whether you obtain the integrand. Of course do not forget to check the book's result (particularly not if your result has the correct derivative). While it's not necessarily immediately obvious that the derivative of the book's answer cannot be transformed into the integrand, if you look at the values at specific points, it becomes clear quickly: At $x = 0$, the book's answer has a negative derivative, but the integrand is positive there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the steps of substitution you showed are correct but your final answer is wrong. It shouldn't be in terms of $\arctan$

if you let $z=\tan \frac{x}{2}\implies dx=\frac{2\ dz}{1+z^2}$ then $$\int \frac{8\ dx}{3\cos 2x+1}$$
$$=\int \frac{8\ dx}{3(2\cos^2x-1)+1}=\int \frac{4\ dx}{3\cos^2x-1}$$

$$=\int \frac{4}{3\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right)^2-1}\frac{2\ dz}{1+z^2}$$
$$=\int \frac{4}{3\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right)^2-1}$$
$$=\int \frac{4(1+z^2)}{z^4-4z^2+1}\ dz$$
$$=4\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{z^2}}{\left(z-\frac 1z\right)^2-2}\ dz$$
$$=4\int \frac{d\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)}{\left(z-\frac 1z\right)^2-(\sqrt 2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{2\sqrt 2}\ln\left|\frac{z-\frac{1}{z}-\sqrt 2}{z-\frac{1}{z}+\sqrt 2}\right|+C$$
substituting back $z=\tan \frac x2$, 
$$=\sqrt 2\ln \left|\frac{\tan\frac{x}{2}-\cot\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt 2}{\tan\frac{x}{2}-\cot\frac{x}{2}+\sqrt 2}\right|+C$$

Comment: I double checked the answer in my book and it is correctly typed in my question. However, Wolfram|Alpha also seems to support there might be a typo in my book:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+8%2F%283cos2x%2B1%29

Comment: I really like your factoring into $(z - \frac{1}{z})$ and your shorthand $d(z-\frac{1}{z})$; I have so much to learn.

Comment: Alright, it may be a typo. But the answer for the question you asked here is not correct that you gave,

Comment: Notice, this problem can be solved more easily if you just substitute  $\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2 x}$

Comment: I added a disclaimer at the top of my question about the likely typo in my book. Thanks for bringing to my attention.

Comment: yes, now the typo in your answer is obvious & the answer in $\log$ is correct as I provided

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\dfrac8{3\cos2x+1}=\dfrac{8\sec^2x}{3(1-\tan^2x)+1+\tan^2x}$$

Now set $\tan x=y$

Comment: I then get $\frac{4(1+y^2)}{2-y^2}$ but I still don't understand how to get arctan which I would expect from an integral like $\int \frac{dy}{a^2 + y^2}$ for example.

Comment: @totembowl, You should get $$\int\dfrac{8dy}{4-2y^2}$$

Comment: I replaced $sec^2 x$ in the numerator with $(1 + \tan^2 x)$ and then $(1 + z^2)$, how did you simplify the numerator?

Comment: @totembowl $sec^2 x dx$ must be written as $dy$.Don't do what you did ^

Comment: Thank you, I missed that $dy = \sec^2 x dx$.

Answer (score 1):

If we are going to make a Weierstrass-style substitution, it seems more natural, because of the $\cos 2x$, to let $z=\tan x$. Then $\cos 2x=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}$ and $dx=\frac{1}{1+z^2}\,dz$. Thus our integral becomes, after a little manipulation,
$$\int\frac{4}{2-z^2}\,dz.$$

Comment: Did you miss a factor $2$ in $dx$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  The substitution I am making is not quite standard Weierstrass, it is $z=\tan x$. So $dz=(\sec^2 x)\,dx=(1+\tan^2  x) \,dx=(1+z^2)\,dx$.

Comment: Ooops ! Shame on me !!!